# Getting Current CultureInfo in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, resources

How can I access the current CultureInfo in a Class? This is what I want to do in my class:

```
   if(!LoggedIn())
    {
        string culture = CultureInfo.Name.replace("-","_"); //here is the Problem
                                                            //I don't know how to access the current CultureInfo
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/" + HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("pages", "login_" + culture);
    }
```

**Edit For Reopening:** This is not a duplicate here I wanted to know how to access culture info from a class and its totally different from the question which simply asks how to know the cultureinfo

Comment: "here is the problem" Mind explaining what the "problem" is?

Comment: well this is where I should get the cultureinfo that I don't have a clue how to do it. In that line `CultureInfo.Name.replace("-","_");` is what I'm tring to do. but I don't know how to access the current cultureinfo

Comment: Do you want the CultureInfo for the current thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing this for the current thread's culture:

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```